# Javafx: Reusable collections using FXML

Tags: java, javafx, collections, fxml

I'd like to bind a single collection to multiple ChoiceBox's in FXML.
However the only way I know how is using:

```xml
<ChoiceBox fx:id="cb00" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:id="test" fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="1" />
            <String fx:value="2" />
            <String fx:value="3" />
            <String fx:value="4" />
            <String fx:value="5" />
            <String fx:value="6" />
            <String fx:value="7" />
            <String fx:value="8" />
            <String fx:value="9" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Is it possible to declare the collection in the controller and refer to it in FXML instead of copying the collection for each ChoiceBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the items in the controller:

```
public class Controller {

    private ListProperty<String> choiceBoxItems = new SimpleListProperty(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    public Controller() {
        IntStream.range(1,10).mapToObj(i -> Integer.toString(i))
            .forEach(choiceBoxItems::add);
    }

    public ListProperty<String> choiceBoxItemsProperty() {
        return choiceBoxItems ;
    }

    public ObservableList<String> getChoiceBoxItems() {
        return choiceBoxItemsProperty().get() ;
    }

    public void setComboBoxItems(ObservableList<String> choiceBoxItems) {
        choiceBoxItemsProperty().set(choiceBoxItems) ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then (this is not tested, but I think it will work):

```xml
<ChoiceBox fx:id="cb00" items="${controller.choiceBoxItems}" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0">
```

See [expression binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) in the FXML documentation. (It's not actually documented that the controller is available in the FXML namespace with key `controller`, but I think it is safe to use this.)

You can also just define the list in the FXML using [`fx:define`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements):

```xml
<fx:define>

    <FXCollections fx:id="choiceBoxItems" fx:factory="observableArrayList">
        <String fx:value="1"/>
        <String fx:value="2"/>
        <String fx:value="3"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </FXCollections>

</fx:define>
```

and then refer to it in each choice box:

```xml
<ChoiceBox fx:id="cb00" items="${choiceBoxItems}" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be in the controller or any other class like (the example is for a combobox. The same can be applied to a choicebox):

**combo.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<ComboBox  fx:id="combo1" items="${itemLoader.items}"  prefWidth="150.0"  
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
</ComboBox>
```

**Loader class**

```
public class ComboLoader {

    private ObservableList<String> obsStrings;

    public ComboLoader() {

        obsStrings = FXCollections.observableArrayList(createStrings());
    }

    private List<String> createStrings() {
            return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 5)
                    .mapToObj(i -> "String "+i)
                    .map(String::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    //name of this method corresponds to itemLoader.items in xml.
    //if xml name was itemLoader.a this method should have been
    //getA(). A bit odd
    public ObservableList<String> getItems(){

        return obsStrings;
    }
}
```

test it with:

```
public class ComboTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Populate combo from custom builder");

        Group group = new Group();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
        group.getChildren().add(grid);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("combo.fxml"));
        loader.getNamespace().put("itemLoader", new ComboLoader());
        ComboBox<String>combo = loader.load();
        grid.add(combo, 0, 0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 450, 175);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`<fx:reference>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#reference_elements) to reference existing objects by their `fx:id`. Using this tag you can reuse the `ObservableList`:

```xml
<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" spacing="10">
    <children>
        <ChoiceBox prefWidth="150.0">
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:id="test" fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <String fx:value="1" />
                    <String fx:value="2" />
                    <String fx:value="3" />
                    <String fx:value="4" />
                    <String fx:value="5" />
                    <String fx:value="6" />
                    <String fx:value="7" />
                    <String fx:value="8" />
                    <String fx:value="9" />
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </ChoiceBox>
        <ChoiceBox prefWidth="150.0">
            <items>
                <fx:reference source="test" /> <!-- reuse other list here -->
            </items>
        </ChoiceBox>
    </children>
</HBox>
```