# Dynamically loads point to a Polygon constructed by FXML

Tags: java, dynamic, javafx-8, fxml

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44355944/3992939) a loader class is used to dynamically load a `ComboBox` while it is constructed (without post processing). 
I wanted to use a similar technique to **pre-process** and reuse a [Polygon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html) , but a Polygon doesn't expose `items` property, or a similar one.
My solution was to extend Polygon and add such property:

```
public class DPolygon extends javafx.scene.shape.Polygon{

    public ObjectProperty<ObservableList<Double>> items =
            new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "items");

    public DPolygon() {
        items.addListener(new ChangeListener<ObservableList<Double>>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ObservableList<Double>>
            observable, ObservableList<Double> oldValue,
            ObservableList<Double> newValue) {
                addPolyPoints();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addPolyPoints() { super.getPoints().setAll(items.get());}

    public ObjectProperty<ObservableList<Double>>itemsProperty() { return items; }

    public final ObservableList<Double> getItems() {return items.get(); }

    public final void setItems(ObservableList<Double> value) {items.set(value); }
}
```

Have a loader class to supply the points:

```
public class PointsLoader5 {

    private ObservableList<Double> items;

    public ObservableList<Double> getItems() {

        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new Double[] {100.,0.,100., 100., 0., 0.});
        return items;
    }
}
```

Use both in the `FXML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.Double?>
<?import javafx.xml_polygon.DPolygon?>

<DPolygon fx:id="triangle" fill="GREEN" stroke="RED" strokeType="INSIDE"
     items="${pointsLoader.items}" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
</DPolygon>
```

And put it all together to test:

```
public class DrawTrianle5 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Set points using loader");
        Group group = new Group();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
        group.getChildren().add(grid);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("triangle/Triangle5.fxml"));
        loader.getNamespace().put("pointsLoader", new PointsLoader5());
        DPolygon triangle = loader.load();

        grid.add(triangle, 0, 0);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 450, 175);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It works with no problem.
My question is: is it the right approach, or is there a better way to dynamically loads point to a `Polygon` constructed by`FXML`, avoiding post-processing ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. " Polygon doesn't expose `items` property, or a similar one." It exposes an `ObservableList<Double> getPoints()`. Why not just use that?

Comment: I don't know how to use it without post-processing the `Polygon`. Could you post an example ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to clarify the problem. What do you mean by "post-processing the polygon"? (Post=after: after *what*?) What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am not trying to solve. I do it as a study. I want to `FXML` construct  `Polygon` s, each with different points as if I was using [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html#Polygon-double...-) constructor. I am trying to avoid constructing an empty `Polygon` and the setting its points (which I call post-processing)

Comment: But you do actually construct an empty polygon... because your `DPolygon` constructor implicitly calls `super()`. The FXML is approximately equivalent to `DPolygon triangle = new DPolygon();` `triangle.setItems(pointsLoader.getItems());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing preventing you doing this with the current `Polygon` class is that there is no suitable constructor argument with a [`@NamedArg` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823157/what-is-the-purpose-of-namedarg-annotation-in-javafx-8).

So one way to do this would be:

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class DPolygon extends Polygon {

    public DPolygon(@NamedArg("points") List<Double> points) {
        super(points.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray());
    }
}
```

Then you just need

```xml
<DPolygon xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" points="$points" fill="GREEN" stroke="RED" strokeType="INSIDE" />
```

Test:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PolygonTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Polygon.fxml"));
        loader.getNamespace().put("points", Arrays.asList(100.0,0.0,100.0,100.0,0.0,0.0));
        Polygon poly = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(poly), 450, 175);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It feels like there should be an approach without the subclass at all, but I can't quite find one that works.

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks. I suggest a small change : `loader.getNamespace().put("points", new double[] {100.0,0.0,100.0,100.0,0.0,0.0});`   which makes `DPolygon` even simpler.